# Passing a vector as argument and using it, why does it crash?

Tags: c++, function, stl, vector, crash

I'm fairly new to C++ especially STL. I'm trying to pass a vector as argument to a function, but it causes the application to crash. I'm using Code::Blocks and MingW. Here is a simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void foo(const vector<int> &v)
{
    cout << v[0];
}
int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    v[0] = 25;
    foo(v);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It crashes because you write past the end of the vector with `v[0]` - that's undefined behaviour. Its inital size is 0 if you do nothing. (You subsequently read the same too, but all bets are off well before that point).

You probably wanted to do:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(25);
foo(v);
```

Or maybe:

```
vector<int> v(1);
v.at(0) = 25;
foo(v);
```

If you use `v.at(n)` instead of the [] operator you will get exceptions thrown rather than undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! I should learn more about STL. I treat a vector as a simple array which is apparently wrong!

Comment: @Physer - a vector is similar to an array in quite a lot of ways. Reading past the end of the vector is no better/worse than reading past the end of an array.

Comment: I see what you mean. This is an excerpt of a larger code that I'm working on. Initially I'd given the vector a size v(100) and populated it using a loop, like v[i] = value; ...

Comment: Well the usual problem with excerpts applies, you get a different question answered from the one you wanted to be answered. Post the real code.